# WebRTC Video Track to ffmpeg in Node

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, webrtc, video-streaming, rtmp

I have succesfully managed to establish a WebRTC connection between Node (server) and a browser. Server gets the video track on **onTrack** callback inside the RTCPeerConnection. Is there any way I can potentially convert the video track and make it work on ffmpeg so I can output it to rtmp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have done this is to use a socket to the node server, and then use ffmpeg to convert to RTMP:

I spawn FFMPEG

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('ffmpeg',['-h']).on('error',function(m){
    console.error("FFMpeg not found in system cli; please install ffmpeg properly or make a softlink to ./!");
    process.exit(-1);
});
```

I make sure Im getting video from the socket, and then I pipe it into FFMPEG and out to my RTMP server:

var ops=[
'-i','-',

```
        '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'ultrafast', '-tune', 'zerolatency',  // video codec config: low latency, adaptive bitrate
        '-c:a', 'aac', '-ar', audioBitrate, '-b:a', audioEncoding, // audio codec config: sampling frequency (11025, 22050, 44100), bitrate 64 kbits
        //'-max_muxing_queue_size', '4000', 
        //'-y', //force to overwrite
        //'-use_wallclock_as_timestamps', '1', // used for audio sync
        //'-async', '1', // used for audio sync
        //'-filter_complex', 'aresample=44100', // resample audio to 44100Hz, needed if input is not 44100
        //'-strict', 'experimental', 
        '-bufsize', '5000',
        
        '-f', 'flv', socket._rtmpDestination
    
        
    ];
}
console.log("ops", ops);
    console.log(socket._rtmpDestination);
    ffmpeg_process=spawn('ffmpeg', ops);
    console.log("ffmpeg spawned");
```

you can see my code:https://github.com/dougsillars/browserLiveStream/blob/master/server.js

and a working example at [livestream.a.video](https://livestream.a.video)